# php html table entries using multiple loops

Tags: php, html

UPDATED: I have been trying to prepare a cross table entry in php html but cant do so. For blank subjects in my table I want to show a link to edit that cell.

My updated code:

```
$days = array("1"=>"Monday", "2"=>"Tuesday", "3"=>"Wednesday", "4"=>"Thursday", "5"=>"Friday", "6"=>"Saturday", "7"=>"Sunday", );

$hours = DB::table('timetablelectures')->select('timetablelectures.id', 'timetablelectures.start_time')
                                ->get();
$timetable = DB::table('timetable')->select('timetable.id', 'timetable.day', 'timetable.lecture_id', 'timetable.subject_id')
                                ->get();
```

//SET UP SCHEDULE

```
$schedule = array();

    foreach($timetable as $tt) 
        {
        foreach($days as $x => $x_value) 
            {
                if ( $tt->day==$x)
                            {
                            $schedule["{$x}"][$tt->lecture_id][] = $tt->subject_id;
                            }
            }
        }


// DISPLAY SCHEDULE, headers first
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr><td align="center">Time</td>
 <?php foreach ( $hours as $hour ) 
                {
                    echo "<td>  $hour->start_time </td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";

foreach ( $days as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "<tr><td>$x_value</td>";

    // roll through days
    foreach ( $hours as $hour ) {
        echo '<td>';
        // check for subjects in this slot
        if ( isset($schedule[$x][$hour->id]) ) {
            // and display each
            foreach ( $schedule[$x][$hour->id] as $subject ) {
                echo "$subject<br>";
            }
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

And I need it as [Correct Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgup9.png) Just instead of blanks a link will be provided o edit the entry

Comment: can u add what output you are getting??

Comment: cann u add the array(s) that contain the data to populate the table